# Drupal Commons make group content visible for anonomous users?

Tags: organic-groups

I have a Drupal (7.52) Commons (commons-7.x-3.40) website which currently requires users to log-in to see published content.

Now I need to publish content so it is visible to non-authenticated users... I'm not sure the best way to accomplish this.  I'm not very experienced with Drupal, the most logical thing to me would be to simply create a new Group which allows anyone (anyone|Any site member can contribute) to view content but this option seems to still require authentication.

Other options seem to be add:

- new content-Type e.g. Public_Group (or perhaps Public_Page)
- new role for unauthenticated users (e.g. called anyone), or
- a module like this: https://www.drupal.org/project/og_visibility ?

Not sure where to start looking - please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution - in Permissions (People), check 'Anonymous User' for the 'Node' setting 'View Published Content'.